# Does feedback has default value in oracle, if yes where is it set?

Tags: oracle, shell, feedback

I am running the below query in 2 different DBs

```
echo "SET HEADING OFF
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT FAILURE;
select distinct mkt_cd from $TEMP_MKT_TABLE;
EXIT;" > $DISTINCT_MARKET_SQL
sqlplus -s ${CONNECT_STRING} @$DISTINCT_MARKET_SQL >> text.txt
```

But in 1 DB i am getting the feedback as "NUMBER OF ROWS SELECTED" and in other DB i am not getting this FEEDBACK. I am not explicitly setting feedback in nay DB. I want to know that Why is it different in the 2 DBs? Can feedback have default value in different DBs? If yes where do we set the default value?

Comment: Inspect glogin.sql and possibly also login.sql (if it exists on either client machine). This has nothing to do with the database; "feedback" is a setting on the client software, SQL\*Plus. You may have different users with different `login.sql` in which they set different values for `feedback`, using the same copy of SQL\*Plus and running the same query against the same DB, and still getting different feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default value is 6. The default value is set in glogin.sql, in $ORACLE_HOME/sqlplus/admin